# Inverse M matrices sufficient condition for reversing inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am asking out of curiosity, from a related question: [Element-wise ordering of the inverse of two M-matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087838/element-wise-ordering-of-the-inverse-of-two-m-matrices).
I know that in general the converse is not true. 
But suppose that we are given an inverse M matrix $A$ and identity matrix $I$ with $A \leq I$ (entrywise ordering), when can we say $A^{-1}\geq I$ holds true? 
Try: Because $A$ is an inverse M matrix, I tried by assuming, suppose $A^{-1}$ is strictly diagonally dominant, then manipulate to show that the inequality will reverse, but so far no luck. Any hint or idea to try pursue will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A\le I$, $A$ is a diagonal matrix. Since $A$ is the inverse of an $M$-matrix, it is a positive diagonal matrix. The assumption $A\le I$ thus implies that all diagonal entries of $A$ lie inside $(0,1]$. Hence $A^{-1}\ge I$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, can I please ask you here itself, what if the inequality is reversed. What condition can we put to ensure that the result holds true. (with all inequalities reversed).

Comment: @user812951 What do you mean by "the result"?

Comment: If A is greater than or equal to identity matrix (entry-wise), with the above conditions on A, when can inverse of A be less than or equal to identity matrix.

Comment: @user812951 Let me think about it.

Comment: If A is an inverse M matrix, entry-wise greater than or equal to identity matrix, we only know that its inverse will be M matrix, but its inverse need not be necessarily less than or equal to identity matrix. Can we put the assumption that inverse of A is strictly diagonally dominant for the inequality to hold true. Or can we put any other assumption.